# Not able to pass value to the function triggered by onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

The function named buildSub(data) and it's implementation is shown below.
      I am trying to pass value to the function named dispProductCategoryWise(par1,par2,par3) in it.

```
  function buildSub(data) {
    tempCategoriesList ='';
    var len = data.length;
    if (len > 0) {
        for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var subcat = data[i];
            tempCategoriesList =  tempCategoriesList
            + $.trim(
                    "<li><a href='#' onclick=dispProductCategoryWise('"+subcat.name+"','"+subcat.id+"','60');>"+subcat.name+"</a></li>"


            );
        } 

    }
    return tempCategoriesList;
}
```

The problem is that when subcat.name = "Dry Fruits". The function is not been called. When i inspect element in browser i see the following output.

```
<a href="#" onclick="dispProductCategoryWise('Dry"  Fruits','105','60');="">Dry Fruits</a>
```

It is passing double quotes when it encounters space in the variable name.

When subcat.name = "Almonds" i.e; without any space. The function is called and works properly. When i inspect element in browser i see the following output.

```
<a href="#" onclick="dispProductCategoryWise('Almonds','106','60');">Almonds</a>
```

This is how the value should be passed. Please help me. Why it is not passing  proper value when it has space in it? Sorry if i made any typing and grammatical  mistakes.

Comment: Hi.. I value is been passed properly from the html. But the problem is when i pass the value with space in it.

Comment: if space is not required in value then trim that string so that solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not escape the single quote, write like this :

```
"<li><a href='#' onclick=\"dispProductCategoryWise('"+subcat.name+"','"+subcat.id+"','60');\">"+subcat.name+"</a></li>"
```

Comment: Initially i tried the same way but no success. When value with space in it is passed then the same problem happens.

Comment: check now i have put the function inside double quotes

Comment: It is working.Thanks a lot bro... helped me a lot. But can you explain me the what was the problem and how you sorted it out?

Comment: Your welcome. Certainly, an attribute value is always inside the quotes. It is the general syntax. Accept the answer if it helped please.